# Better Way to Check LLVM Out?

Tags: git, cmake, llvm, xcode6.1

I've been looking at LLVM lately and have been using the following sequence of Terminal commands to check it out of the LLVM project's Git repository:

`cd /Volumes/Development/Repositories/llvm
git fetch && git checkout master && git pull
cd ./tools/clang
git fetch && git checkout master && git pull
cd ../../projects/compiler-rt
git fetch && git checkout master && git pull
cd ../test-suite
git fetch && git checkout master && git pull
cd /Volumes/Development/Repositories/llvm/build
rm -Rv ./*.*
cmake -G "Xcode" /Volumes/Development/Repositories/llvm
open ./LLVM.xcodeproj`

The problem with this procedure is that it always wipes my slate completely blank:  I lose any breakpoints I've set, not to *mention* any work Xcode's done toward building and maintaining the new project's search index (and *that* takes several computationally-intensive *hours* to regenerate.)  So, my question is if there might be a better way to check LLVM out that doesn't make it so that I have to start over every time I touch base with the LLVM repository and sync my copy with it.  I *know* Xcode can base a project off of what's in a repository, but I'm not sure I should do that since what CMake does when it creates a project out of a repository's contents is *probably* different from what Xcode does in such a situation.  Would it be safe for me to go ahead and just use only Xcode's built-in tools for communicating with remote repositories, or should I try and get CMake back into the loop somehow after I've let Xcode do its thing?

Comment: Just a comment, as I have no means to verify this currently: The problem is most likely the `rm -Rv`. Try to remove that command. The rest of the commands can be left as they are. CMake should update your project files accordingly and you should only have to recompile what changed. Note though that XCode has a tendency to get confused if too many changes happen at once. So you still might find the need to do a full rebuild after fetching, but that should only happen occasionally.

Comment: @ComicSansMS:  Huh.  I'm _pretty_ sure that, _last_ time I tried this without ``rm -Rv ./*.*``, CMake balked at me when I tried that.  I'll try it again and see what happens.

Comment: @ComicSansMS:  Now _that's_ weird; CMake was _perfectly happy_ to update my existing project _this_ time around.  I must have done something else weird that I can't remember last time….

Comment: @ComicSansMS:  I think I've figured out why CMake balked at updating my copy of the LLVM project last time!  It seems that newer versions of CMake can't regenerate projects generated by older versions of the program, so updating CMake currently forces users to generate new copies of their projects for use with their IDEs from _scratch_ every single time one does that….

Comment: Note: `git fetch` is useless, `git checkout master && git pull` is enough and produce the same result (unless you deleted the master branch...).